# Problem with MYSQL function and GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I created the database function below. When I run it however, the result is not ordered correctly, nor is the LIMIT applied. For example, my data returned is:

```
31471|31471.jpg,31472|31472.jpg,31473|31473.jpg,31474|31474.jpg,31475|31475.jpg,31476|31476.jpg,31478|31478.jpg,31479|31479.jpg
```

As you can see, there are more than 3 results (LIMIT did not work) and the id's are ascending when they should be descending, even though it's ordered by Date (ORDER BY not working)

The only thing that is different with this function is the GROUP_CONCAT. Is it causing the issue and why. If not, what's the problem with the function then??

Thanks

```
    DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `fnAlbumGetRecentPhotoList` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `fnAlbumGetRecentPhotoList`(_albumId int) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

  -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Gets a list of 3 most recent photos for an album
  -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------

  DECLARE _outRecentPhotoList VARCHAR(1024);

  SET _outRecentPhotoList = (
                              SELECT (CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(photoId, '|', photoFileName)) AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)) AS recentPhotoList
                              FROM photo
                              WHERE photoAlbumId = _albumId
                              ORDER BY photoCSD DESC
                              LIMIT 0,3
                            );

  RETURN _outRecentPhotoList;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP_CONCAT() returns a single row, so applying LIMIT and ORDER to it will not give you what you want.

If you embed the LIMIT and ORDER BY in a sub-query you can get the 3 rows you want, and then concatenate them.

Like this:

```
SELECT (CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(photoId, '|', photoFileName)) AS CHAR(10000) 
  CHARACTER SET utf8)) AS recentPhotoList
FROM 
(
SELECT photoId,photoFileName
FROM photo
WHERE photoAlbumId = _albumId
ORDER BY photoCSD DESC
LIMIT 0,3
) as sub_query
```

Comment: Is it not possible to Cast columns of Group_CONCAT to varchar(255) datatype?

Comment: @user4033385: no, CAST() only supports certain types, including CHAR but not VARCHAR: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: @lke Walker I have ETL job which requires Group_Concat() column to be varchar. Any possible workaround, please advise. I checked in MySQL reference not able to find

Comment: @user4033385 there is no reason you can't insert the output of GROUP_CONCAT() into a VARCHAR column. If you are having a problem I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: @lke Walker I need to rephrase my ask. I have existing column in base table as varchar(25) and I am creating a View and  GROUP_CONCAT() is set to a column and it is shown as 'text' datatype in show create view. Is it possible to have 'VARCHAR(25)' datatype for GROUP_CONCAT() column. Please advise

Comment: @user4033385 Ask that as a new question and link to it here. Your question is not directly related to this question, so this is not the right place to address it.